# One To Many, Many To Many

Tags: laravel

```
$trell = Trell::find($trell_id);

$builder = $trell->builders();

$codes = $builder->codes(); //Undefined method codes...
```

So I get Undefined method on codes, my relationships are like the following: Why doesn't it work?

Trell has one defined in the Model:

```
public function builders() {
    return $this->hasOne('Appsales\\Models\\Builders');
}
```

Builder has codes defined:

```
public function codes() {
    return $this->hasMany('Appsales\\Models\\Codes');
}
```

Codes has:

```
public function builders() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Appsales\\Models\\Builders');
}

$trell->with('builders.codes')->get()->toArray(); works, but I only want "one codes" with some filtering (where in the sql) that is.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the call to a relationship-function doesn't return a model but a Relationship.

```
<?php

$trell = Trell::find($trell_id);

$builder = $trell->builders();
/**
 * $builder is now of type \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 * which does not have a method codes()
 * But you don't want the relationship, you want the property as a Model.
 * So you call it as property and not as a function
 */

$builderModel = $trell->builders;

$codes = $builderModel->codes;

/**
 * Now $codes contains all codes as collection of models. If you want to
 * filter them, you get it as Relationship / Query object and use the 
 * regular query builder functions:
 */

$codes = $builderModels->codes()->where('key', $value)->get();
```

You can even load everything from the Trell Model:

```
$trells = Trell::with([

   'builders.codes' => function($query) {

        $query->where('key1', $value1);

   },

])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `$builder = $trell->builders();` is not returning a *builders* object, it returns a query builder object, so when it looks for *codes()* method it doesn't exists.

Replacing that line with `$builder = $trell->builders;` should work.